# Inconsistent figsize resizing in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have several different barplot figures to generate with a varying amount of bars. The total width and height of the figure thus varies, but I would like the bars to be consistently sized the same for all barplots.

What I tried so far is to resize the figsize proportionally to the number of bars. This does not seem to work consistently.

Here is a sample code:

```
nb_bars_list = [2, 10]

for i, nb_bars in enumerate(nb_bars_list):
    # Resize proportionally to the number of bars
    figsize = [1+nb_bars, 5]
    # Prepare the ticks
    ticks = np.arange(1, 1+nb_bars, 1)
    # Generate random points
    points = [np.random.randn(10) for x in xrange(nb_bars)]
    # Make the plot
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    if figsize:
        fig.set_size_inches(figsize[0], figsize[1], forward=True)
    for b in xrange(nb_bars):
        ax.bar(ticks[b], points[b].mean())
    fig.savefig('test%i' % i, bbox_inches='tight')
```

Which results in:
[image: 2-bars]
[image: 10-bars]

If we overlap both using GIMP, we can clearly notice the difference in bar widths:

[image: both-bars]

How can I ensure the same width for the bars, whatever the number of bars?

I am using matplotlib 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To set the figure size such that different numbers of bars in a figure always have the same width would require to take the figure margins into account. Also one would need to set the xlimits of the plot equally in all cases.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

nb_bars_list = [2, 10]
margleft = 0.8 # inch
margright= 0.64 # inch
barwidth = 0.5 # inch


for i, nb_bars in enumerate(nb_bars_list):
    # Resize proportionally to the number of bars
    axwidth = nb_bars*barwidth # inch
    figsize = [margleft+axwidth+margright, 5]
    # Prepare the ticks
    ticks = np.arange(1, 1+nb_bars, 1)
    # Generate random points
    points = [np.random.randn(10) for x in xrange(nb_bars)]
    # Make the plot
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=figsize)
    fig.subplots_adjust(left=margleft/figsize[0], right=1-margright/figsize[0])

    for b in xrange(nb_bars):
        ax.bar(ticks[b], points[b].mean())
    ax.set_xlim(ticks[0]-0.5,ticks[-1]+0.5)
    #fig.savefig('test%i' % i, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Just perfect! Thanks a lot!

Comment: NB: don't use `plt.tight_layout()` or use it before `fig.subplot_adjust()`, else it won't work!

Comment: That is correct. This whole solution is based on setting the subplot parameters. If you call `tight_layout` it will just calculate its own best fitting subplot parameters and overwrite anything set before.